# Not well formed error while accessing JSON with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

So I have a JSON file whose contents I wish to access and store in an array. Everything seems to be working fine but I am getting an error in Firefox console.

```
Not Well Formed.
```

and it is pointing to my JSON. I validated my JSON at [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) and it says "Valid JSON".

My jquery is:

```
$(function(){


$('#test').click(function(event){

$.getJSON("myfile.json",function(data){

var items=[];

$.each(data, function(key, val){

items.push(key + "," + val[0].subject + "," + val[0].room);

});
alert('transfer successful');
console.log(items);

});

});

});
```

My JSON looks something like this:

```
{
"8": [ {"subject":"Signals","room":"L20"} ],
"9": [ {"subject":"something","room":"L20"} ]
}
```

It may here be noted that this code is working fine with the `items` array getting populated as expected. But I cannot understand why I am getting the `Not well formed` error.

Comment: The final comma should not be there in your JSON string, it is ill-formed.

Comment: @JonathanM i think this is just a snippet.

Comment: @Akshay, please post actual JSON or a link to it.

Comment: @JonathanM, The final comma is not there indeed. Actually my whole JSON is similar to one I posted, but instead of 2 rows, it has 8 rows. I truncated it before posting it to SO, and in doing that, I forgot the last comma to remove.

Comment: @reyaner, where do I place those `[..]`. Sorry, I am a beginner.

Comment: don't understand why use a object if you have to list your array with numbers "8", "9" and go on. Sometimes using numbers instead of letters for property name can cause multiple issues.

Answer (score 0):

This happens in FireFox when Content-Type is not set. Ensure you are returning the correct mimetype for your `myfile.json` request ("application/json" etc.)

Comment: @FelixKling It does just fine; the warning is rooted from FireFox, not jQuery. As OP mentions, everything works fine, he/she was just concerned about the warning log statement.